SERA.8012 and ATS.TR.220 Wake Turbulence Separation application
I need small clarification on current European documents SERA and Part-ATS.
Based on SERA.8012(a):

(a) Air traffic control units shall apply wake turbulence separation
minima to aircraft in the approach and departure phases of flight
in any of the following circumstances

Part-ATS ATS.TR.220 states different time-based and distance-based separation intervals, but, for instance, not a time nor distance interval is specified for LIGHT acft following LIGHT acft. For example, 2 Cessna 172 flying IFR, ILS approach to the same runway, so Wake Turb Separation to be applied (exception made for VFR-VFR and IFR making visual approach following IFR traffic).
In RECAT-EU (Part-ATS AMC7 ATS.TR.220) distances for non-covered cases are marked as:

(*) means that the separation minimum to be applied is the horizontal
separation minimum based on an ATS surveillance system (established in
accordance with AMC1 ATS.TR.210(c)(2)), and should remain compatible
with runway capacity.

but for time intervals it's still not clear.

In case there is no published distance/time for pair of aircraft (like LIGHT-LIGHT), what separation shall be used in airport not applying RECAT? I would assume the interval always shall be the minimum of zone (e.g. 3 nm for TMA/CTR), and reduced/increased only when Wake turbulence pair exists. But I have no proof in docs, it can be interpreted differently.
SERA describes "approach and departure phases of flight", then Part-ATS covers either departing, or arriving cases. Shall the wake turbulence separation be applied between traffic just taken-off and about to land on the same runway? My gut feeling about safety says yes, wake turbulence separation shall be applied to ALL traffic within 1000 feet/same runway, but I see no exact case in the Rules.
In case of class D airspace, where IFR and VFR are informed about each other, imagining LIGHT Cessna 182 IFR coming behind LIGHT Cessna 152 doing VFR landing, there is no wake turbulence separation case in documents, and there is no separation by airspace class, so they can fly in whatever interval literally? (taking into account runway occupancy time and landing clearance allowance, for sure).

p.s. At some airports such shady cases are covered as "In any case separation is not specified by docs, minimum separation shall be 3 nm for all traffic coming to the same runway", but I do know, that not all the airports have it stated in local rules.




Different separation minima apply in different airspaces and different situations. For radar environments, 5 or 3 NM are common values (sometimes 2,5 NM on final approach). Vertical separation is usually 1000 ft. In non-radar environments, procedural separation minima apply, for example aircraft tracking away from a radio beacon have to be on tracks diverging by a certain number of degrees and a certain distance from the beacon. These minima always apply, and have nothing to do with wake turbulence.
Wake turbulence separation minima are applied in addition to normal separation minima. This means that whenever the wake turbulence separation minima are larger than the general applicable minima, those need to be applied. For example, the general separation minima for an airspace might be 3 NM, but in the case of a medium aircraft following a heavy, this has to be increased to 5 NM. When the wake turbulence separation minima are smaller - or non existing, such as the case with a light following another light - the controller only has to apply the general separation minima (for example 3 NM or 1000 ft). You can never reduce the required separation below the general minima applicable for the airspace.
2.
Yes, wake turbulence separation must also be applied between a preceeding departing aircraft and a succeeding arriving aircraft. The logic here is that the arriving aircraft might execute a missed approach at any point, in which case wake turbulence might become an issue.
3.
Correct. No specific airborne minima apply, but the controller must ensure there is never a risk of collision and that the runway separation minima are applied (could be reduced runway separation minima, if implemented).
P.s.
There are ALWAYS separation minima for ALL parts of controlled airspace. If you can't find them in the local rules, it is because they are not different from the minima described in the general rules (i.e. EU 373/2017 or national regulations). There is nothing "shady" about that.

Logically I do agree that separations should be applied in addition. Either radar, or wake turbulence. But then in class D that means there is no separation IFR-VFR at all, so even wake turbulence separation is not applied (since..it's separation still, right?), and only "caution wake turbulence" is used?

@BohdanBessonov Wake turbulence separation is still applied during landing and takeoff, regardless of the airspace class.

so it's applied always, but in case there is no matching pair (like Light-Light or Medium-Medium) - zone separation is applied (if it's applicable). Thanks
